# Jmeter compare response with provided file

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing an API and want to make sure it returns the expected result. However the expected result is too big. Every time I tried to copy and paste it in 'Patterns To Test', it got frozen. Now I save the expected result into a file and in the 'Response Assertion' I want to compare the API return against the file to check if they are same.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) instead of copying the file into the "Patterns" section of the response assertion.

   [image]
2. If your response is **really** big I would recommend switching to [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion)

   - Tick `Save response as MD5 hash` box at the "Advanced" tab of the HTTP Request sampler
   - Calculate MD5 checksum of the file, the approaches differ depending on the operating system and software you have, as the majority of the world is on Windows I'd suggest [WinMD5Free](http://www.winmd5.com/), check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps) for other options and more detailed information
   - Replace Response Assertion with MD5Hex Assertion and use the checksum from step 2 instead of full response

     [image]

   The idea is that equal strings have equal hashes and comparing 2 short hashes is faster operation than comparing 2 big strings